# How to format system path to a file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, replace, file-location

I want to read a file say `c.txt` in java in windows. So can anybody suggest me that how can I format a system path to a file say `D:\a\b\c.txt` to `D:/a/b/c.txt` in java? I know it will work like this `D:\\a\\b\\c.txt` but I want to use this `D:/a/b/c.txt`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of your problem but rarely is it good practice to hard code `/` or `\`. Use Java's [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
String file="D:\\a\\b\\c.txt";
file=file.replace('\\','/');
System.out.println(file);
```

output `D:/a/b/c.txt`

But if you are trying to make it more platform dependent you should use `File.separator` (for replacement based on Strings) or `File.separatorChar` (for replacement based on chars).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `char` replace: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29

Example:

```
String pathToFile = "D:\\a\\b\\c.txt";
pathToFile = pathToFile.replace('\\','/'); <-- with ' and not "
```

Documentation of `replace(char, char)`:

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of
>   oldChar in this string with newChar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API

```
File f = new File("c.txt");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
```

or just simply substring

```
String fname = "D:\\a\\b\\c.txt".replace('\\', '/');
System.out.println(fname);
```